# default wordsize in UNIX/Linux

Tags: osx, c, programming, cpu-architecture

I was inspecting the preprocessed output of my C program and happened to look at the header file `wordsize.h`

It is located in 
`/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h`

the file contains only one macro

```
#define __WORDSIZE   32
```

My question is, is the wordsize then being decided by the compiler that is installed or does it has something to do with the OS that I have installed (32 bit or 64 bit) or does it have something to do with the Hardware configuration of my machine.

I am new to development under Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general [`wordsize`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) is decided upon target architecture when compiling. Your compiler will normally compile using `wordsize` for current system.

Using `gcc` (among others) you can also tune this by using various flags. E.g. on a 64-bit host you can compile for [32-bit](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#index-m32-1511) machine, or *force* 32-bit words.

```
-m32  # int, long and pointer to 32 bits, generates code for i386.
-m64  # int, long and pointer to 64 bits, generates code for x86-64.
-mx32 # int, long and pointer to 32 bits, generates code for x86-64.
```

You should also look at `limits.h` and `inttypes.h` to see the usage of this
definition.

---

For cross-compiling check out [multilib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582218/gcc-compile-a-64-bit-binary-on-32-bit-platform) (*32-bit link on SO*) and search tha web.

Check what flags your GCC was built with by:

```
gcc -v
```

---

As to the sizes they are usually closely related to the central processing unit
and related – such as maximum size of a memory address, size of CPU registers
etc.

For a quick glimpse, you do not need to understand much of this, but depending
on *where you are* it can give some insight:

If you use `gcc` and compile with the `-S` flag you can also look at the [assembly instructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes). Here, a bit confusing, on e.g. 32-bit machine a
word is 16 bit and long is 32-bit. (`__WORDSIZE`)

So e.g. `movl  $123, %eax` means move long (32-bit - `__WORDSIZE`) `123` [to `eax` register](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#General-Purpose_Registers_.28GPR.29), and `movw` means move word (16-bit).

---

This is naming conventions, – and only to say that `WORDSIZE` can mean more
then one thing. You can also come across code where they e.g. define something
like

```
#define WORD_SIZE 16
```

as it all depends on context. If you read data from a file or stream where
source has word-size of 16 bit, this would be natural. Only to point out that
do not always assume word-size means `__WORDSIZE` when read it in code.

---

Example with user defined `WORD_SIZE` would not affect instruction set in the
generated machine code. For GCC in general I would recommend [this book](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/). *(Unfortunately it is a bit old – but have yet to find a similar easy to read more up to date book. (Not that I have looked that hard.) It is short, concise and sweet. And if you only keep in
mind that things can have changed, such as added features etc., it gives good introduction non the less.)*

It gives a quick and nice introduction of the various aspects when compiling.
Look at [chapter 11](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_82.html) for a nice compile chain explanation.

---

I do not know of any options in GCC to compile 16-bit. One way to do it would
be to write in assembly using `.code16` to instruct the code should be 16-bits.

Example:

```
    .file "hello.s"
    .text
    .code16            /* Tel GAS to use 16-bit instructions. */
.globl start, _start
start:
_start:
    movb $0x48, %al
        ...
```

This is needed by e.g. boot loaders such as GRUB and LILO for the code
present at `MBR` on your hard drive.

Reason for this is that when your computer boots up the CPU is in a special
mode where it does not have 32-bit but max 16-bit instructions AKA 
[*Real Mode*](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode).

In short what happens is that BIOS do a hardware test, then it
loads the first 512 bytes of your boot disk into memory and leaves control to
that code starting at address `0`. This code in turn locates where next stage
of files reside, load these into memory and continue executing finally entering 
[*Protected Mode*](http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode) where you have *normal* 32-bit mode.

Comment: after reading your answer i want to ask that if the WORDSIZE has been defined as 16bits then would that show some effect on the opcode that is generated by GCC when i compile with the -S flag. i mean would the instructions be different.

Comment: @ArunKumar: No, it would not affect the assembly code. I should have been more consistent in using `__WORDSIZE` in my answer as well. Never use underscore in front of defines (unless you really know what you are doing) as they are (normally) reserved for the compiler. Also if you added a define like `__WORDSIZE 16` that would most likely be overruled by the compiler to 32. If you want to cross-compile 64-bit code on a 32-bit machine you would also need [multilib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582218/gcc-compile-a-64-bit-binary-on-32-bit-platform). Note that this adds a lot of extra.

Comment: i am looking into multilib.. heard about it ryt now only and also tried the -m32, -m64 and -mx32 flags. all compilation except the one with -m32 failed. can i assume that i dont have a multilib gcc installed on my system. how do i check for that?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what mine has:

```
% cat /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h 
/* Determine the wordsize from the preprocessor defines.  */

#if defined __x86_64__
# define __WORDSIZE 64
# define __WORDSIZE_COMPAT32    1
#else
# define __WORDSIZE 32
#endif
```

So it's determined by `wordsize.h`, which comes with your compiler. But an intelligent one will select an appropriate size.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to choose the default wordsize at compilation time, generally by using one of the `-m32` or `-m64` options.

`/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h` is designed to be used when compiling 32 bit applications.

There should be a `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h` containing a 64 bit `__WORDSIZE` definition.

This change was introduced with Ubuntu 11.4: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec

If `-m64` fails, you might have a 32 bit distribution. `uname -m` will tell you.

Although it is possible to cross compile 64 bit binaries on a 32 bit system, that would be inconvenient as you won't have any simple way to run them there.

If your CPU is a 64 bit model (check with `lscpu`), you might want to install a 64 bit distribution to be able to easily build multiarch packages.